# Determine if cipher suite is weak

Tags: tls, cipher-selection

I'm wondering if there is a way I can determine if a cipher suite is weak using python code. For example given this cipher suite as input: `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA` I would want my code to return the fact that it's bad because there is **no forward secrecy**. I'm not asking for python code, I'm just wondering if anyone knows of any good resources that I can use in order to do this (i.e an API call that can give me the score of the cipher suite and reason for scoring)

Thanks!

Comment: You are asking if there is a public database that lists all the problems that a cipher suite can have that you can call with an API. Requests for products/services are generally off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no library.

You can look at the [Qualys SSL Labs rating guide](https://github.com/ssllabs/research/wiki/SSL-Server-Rating-Guide) (not fully updated, you need to look at [their blog](https://blog.qualys.com/ssllabs) to see latest updates).

You can look at the [source code of testssl.sh](https://github.com/drwetter/testssl.sh/blob/3.0/testssl.sh#L5710) for inspiration, it tries to do the same thing.

I would just list [IETF IANA cipher suite IDs](https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xhtml#tls-parameters-4) that are "good" and call all the other "bad", or have "good", "ok" and "bad".

Note that testssl.sh works with openssl names, not IETF names. You may need to [translate](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/ciphers.html#CIPHER-SUITE-NAMES).